# Separate elements from BeautifulSoup Resultset

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and BeautifulSoup(4) in which I need to **scrape** some data without knowing the exact structure of HTML but by making an assumption that user's relevant information will be in `headings, paragraph, pre and code` tags. After `find_all` for these tags, I want to separate the `headings and paragraph` tags from `code and pre` tags from ResultSet object.

Here's what I have tried:

```
required_tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "pre", "code", "p"]
text_outputs = []
code_outputs = []
pages = [
        "https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1803780",
        "https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1780224",
        "https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/_modules/keystone/assignment/core.html",
        "https://openstack-news.blogspot.com/2018/11/bug-1803780-confusing-circular.html",
        "https://www.suse.com/documentation/suse-openstack-cloud-9/doc-cloud-upstream-user/user"
        "/html/keystone/_modules/keystone/assignment/core.html"
    ]


page = requests.get(pages[0])
    html_text = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    text = html_text.find_all(required_tags)
    elements = []
    for e in html_text:
        elements.append(e.parent)
    for t in text:
        for e in elements:
            if e == 'code' or e == 'pre':
                print(e)
                code_outputs.append(t.get_text())
            else:
                text_outputs.append(t.get_text())
```

But it doesn't return anything in `code_outputs` and `text_outputs`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What url are you trying to parse? Please add that

Comment: it's a list of urls, let me add that!

Comment: Yes, add all relevant code to reduce the guesswork

Comment: Hi @DeveshKumarSingh I have added all the `urls`.

Comment: can you double check if the url's you have actually have a code and pre tag? I don't think all of them have

Comment: yes, e.g the third url has a `pre` tag which includes a code snippet.

Comment: The line `if e == 'code' or e == 'pre':` is not checking if the tags are equal to `code` or `pre`, its checking if the entire element is equal to the string `code`or the string `pre`, witch is never the case.

and I dont see the need for this nested for loop.
`for t in text:
        for e in elements:`
Why do you toop over every element in elements for every element i text?

Answer (score 0):

Just get parent name from element like

```
t.parent.name =='code'
```

Rather than creating a list of parent elements.

Comment: it's not fetching the results from `code` and `pre`, for example, if you will see the third-page url, we have a `pre` tag for a code snippet which should be in the `code_outputs` but it's not fetched.

Comment: You are only opening the first page

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any data because you iterate extra inner for loop which is not required

```
 for e in elements:
     if e == 'code' or e == 'pre':
```

See above condition, you iterating parent tag inside child tag list for loop and also comparing `tag object with the string`. you are already getting pre tag data in `text` list object.

```
for page in pages:
    res = requests.get(page)
    html_text = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    text = html_text.find_all(required_tags)   
    for t in text:
        if t.name == 'code' or t.name == 'pre':
            print("===if===")
            code_outputs.append(t.get_text())
        else:
            print("===else===")
            text_outputs.append(t.get_text())

print(code_outputs)
print(text_outputs)
```

**Update:**

```
json_data = []
for page in pages:
    res = requests.get(page)
    html_text = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    text = html_text.find_all(required_tags)
    for t in text:
        if t.name == 'code' or t.name == 'pre':
            code_outputs.append(t.get_text())
        else:
            text_outputs.append(t.get_text())

    data = {page:{"html":text,"code_outputs":code_outputs,"text_outputs":text_outputs}}
    json_data.append(data)

print(json_data)
```

Comment: Ok, how can I add the link with the results also, because the final output should be a list which contains the link and it's text and code.

Comment: It's adding links and relevant information separately, I have to add the link and then it's specific text or code.

Comment: can we formatted the code snipppets in the response? it's looking very weired!

Comment: @Abdul Rehman what you want, scrap website text or just store filtered HTML

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

required_tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "pre", "code", "p"]
text_outputs = []
code_outputs = []
pages = [
        "https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1803780",
        "https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1780224",
        "https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/_modules/keystone/assignment/core.html",
        "https://openstack-news.blogspot.com/2018/11/bug-1803780-confusing-circular.html",
        "https://www.suse.com/documentation/suse-openstack-cloud-9/doc-cloud-upstream-user/user"
        "/html/keystone/_modules/keystone/assignment/core.html"
    ]


page = requests.get(pages[2], verify=False)


html_text = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
elements = {}


for tag in required_tags:
    data=list(html_text.find_all(tag))
    data = [dat.text for dat in data]
    if tag == "code" or tag=="pre":
        code_outputs+=data
    else:
        text_outputs+=data
```